# Set webview height to 70% of its parent in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make webview occupy only 70% of linear layout's height and ad banner occupies the remaining 30%. What my code does is it sets webview width to 70% instead of height. Here is my code

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_light">

    <WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <com.amazon.device.ads.AdLayout
        android:id="@+id/adview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, there were similar questions here, but the solutions don't seem to work. Probably I'm missing something obvious.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try changing the height of webview to `match_parent`.

Comment: oops noticed something just now...try changing `android:layout_weight` to `.7` and `.3` instead of `7` and `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is happening because the default orientation for a LinearLayout is horizontal, that is why the weight attribute is applied to width rather than height. Use this in your LinearLayout, I think it will solve your problem.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"//This is the line that you need to add.
    android:background="@color/primary_light">
```